# Run multiple commands using dockerfile

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

We want to run multiple commands when the docker container starts, the commands are listed below,

1. For starting gunicorn->
   gunicorn --workers 5 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 main:app
2. Move into some directory using->
   cd queues
3. Run the command in the directory->
   celery -A worker worker

Can you please guide us with the steps for this?

We have tried many solutions provided here and there but none seems to work for us. In some cases first command is run but second command doesn't run.

Please refer the dockerfile below:

```
FROM #####.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/python3:latest

MAINTAINER admin

RUN apt-get update -y
    
COPY . /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

COPY startup.sh /app
RUN chmod +x /app/startup.sh

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Edit:

Please find the startup.sh file below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

gunicorn --workers 5 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 main:app
cd queues
celery -A worker worker
```

When the container is run, gunicorn server starts with 5 workers, but celery worker doesn't start up. I have worker.py file inside queues directory.

I know its not working as I have an API which puts some data in db and the worker is supposed to read that and update the db but its not doing that. I am able to test it out on EC2 where I am not using docker.

Comment: Which command doesn't run? How do you know that? Why you don't share the startup.sh script with us?

Comment: I have updated the question based on the comment, can someone please look into it now?

Comment: You would almost always run these in two separate containers.  [Celery and Flask in same docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098668/celery-and-flask-in-same-docker-compose) has an example (though note it uses the archaic version 1 Compose syntax).

Comment: thanks a lot @David, I was able to run separate containers.

Answer (score 0):

The gunicorn command is a blocking command. That means, the command never ends and the rest of your code isn't executed.

To make it work, you have to start it as deamon.

```bash
gunicorn --daemon --workers 5 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 main:app
```

But, splitting the containers up is indeed the cleanest solution.