# How to run python script running when django server starts

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, kafka-python

How to run python script running when django server starts. For example, I have a python kafka script , this script should be running continously when django server starts. when i give two commands in Dockerfile like:

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8443"]
CMD [ "python", "./consumer.py"]
```

only the latest cmd it is picking up. 
Any idea how to start python script and django server using single cmd.

how to start python script and django server using single cmd.

Comment: a) write a start script b) use a separate container for the second task c) use a process controller like supervisord …

Comment: The Compose file in [Celery and Flask in same docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098668/celery-and-flask-in-same-docker-compose) would be a fairly typical setup, running two containers off the same image but overriding the `command:` in one of them to run the other process.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, add a line to copy a custom startup script into the container. For example:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
```

Create a file named entrypoint.sh and add the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8443 &

python consumer.py

tail -f /dev/null
```

In your Dockerfile, use the following CMD instruction:

```
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```